# Выполнится ли блок finally?

Tags: c#, try-catch

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("file.txt");
    try
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
    catch (StackOverflowException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        file.WriteLine("Error");
        file.Close(); 
    }
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: Да. Он для того и существует.

Comment: Просто много раз встречалась фраза: "Блок finally выполняется независимо от того, возникло иключение или нет". Этот понятно. Но что если исключение возникло и не было отловлено в catch?

Comment: Да, при условии, что до выполнения связки try{}catch{}finally{} вообще дойдёт дело.

Comment: Вот у Вас уже есть пример кода с исключением, catch и finally. Зачем принимать на веру ответы из Интернета, если то, что Вас интересует, можно легко выяснить?

Comment: Как я понимаю вопрос заключается в том, что например возникнет исключение, как в Java, NullPointerException. И будет ли выполнен блок finally.

Comment: Вопрос в том, должен ли выполнятся блок finally, если подходящий обработчик catch не был найден и вызван стандартный?

Comment: Хм.. вот тут (в т.ч. и я) отвечают, что выполнится, а тем временем При выполнении как под отладчиком так и скомпиленого ехешника ловит экепшн на уровне try. Но при этом в C# interactive сначала отрабатывает finaly а потом уже эксепшн ловится...

Comment: Вот и у меня просто вываливается ошибка стандартного обработчика (что и понятно, ведь подходящий обработчик я не описал), а блок finally не выполняется. И то что catch можно вообще убрать, оставив только try{}finally{}, меня ставит в тупик.

Comment: Если ещё кто-то не читал: [Finally!](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales).

Answer (score 2):

A-a-a, я, кажется, начинаю понимать, что Вы имели в виду.

Выполнение `finally` не зависит от типа исключения указанного в `catch`.

Ваш код эквивалентен:

```
try 
{ 
  try 
  { 
     throw new DivideByZeroException(); 
  } 
  catch (StackOverflowException e) 
  { 
    ... 
  }
} 
finally 
{ 
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> При возникновении исключения общеязыковая среда выполнения (CLR) ищет оператор catch, который обрабатывает это исключение.  Если текущий выполняемый метод не содержит такой блок catch, среда CLR выполняет поиск в методе, который вызвал текущий метод, и так далее вверх по стеку вызовов.  Если блок catch не находится, то среда CLR отображает пользователю сообщение о необработанном исключении и останавливает выполнение программы.  (c) [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

По finally:

> С помощью блока finally можно выполнить очистку всех ресурсов,
>   выделенных в блоке try, и можно запускать код даже при возникновении
>   исключения в блоке try.  Как правило, операторы блока finally
>   выполняются, когда элемент управления покидает оператор try.  Передача
>   управления может возникать в результате выполнения нормального
>   выполнения, break, continue, goto или оператора return, или
>   распространения исключения из оператора try.
>
> В рамках обработки исключений, связанный блок finally гарантированно
>   будет выполнен.    Однако если исключения необработано, то выполнение
>   блока finally зависит от того, как активирована операция очистки
>   исключения.    Это, в свою очередь, зависит от того, как настроен
>   компьютер.   Дополнительные сведения см. в статье Обработка
>   необработанных исключений в CLR. (c) [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)

Таким образом выходит, что выполнение блока `finally{}` происходит после выхода из блока `try{}` В случае если в `try{}` происходит ошибка которая не перехватывается ни одним из `catch{}` в дереве вызовов и не может быть проигнорирована ( системный диалог об ошибке с "продолжить") то выполнение из блока  `try{}` не выходит, и, соответственно, `finally{}` не отрабатывает.
Если выход за `try{}` возможен т.к. есть перехват исключения выше по стеку вызовов, то сначала выполняется его блок `finally{}`, а уже за тем отрабатывает блок `catch{}` перехватывающий исключение. Если ошибка игнорируется то отрабатывает  блок `finally{}` и выполнение программы продолжается далее по коду...

Comment: Лихое умозаключение. Только неправильное. "то выполнение из блока  try{} не выходит" - это как?

Comment: @Igor заключение сделано на основе статьи на MSDN'e: "... Однако если исключения необработано, то выполнение блока finally зависит от того, как активирована операция очистки исключения. Это, в свою очередь, зависит от того, как настроен компьютер." Тестовые примеры консольных приложений подтверждают данное умозаключение. Если считаете, что я ошибаюсь - приведите пример кода где на уровне try{} происходит неперехваченное/необработанное/непроигнорированное исключение и при этом отрабатывает finaly{}

Comment: ""то выполнение из блока try{} не выходит" - это как? " например так: пользователю отображается сообщение об ошибке, выполнение программы прерывается. Соответственно поток выполняющий код в котором произошла ошибка останавливается когда оператор управления находится в блоке try{} т.е. выхода за рамки этого блока не происходит ввиду остановки потока. Вот как-то так...

Comment: Всем спасибо за внимание. @Alexey, вам особенно.